# How to emulate device-width with puppeteer?

Tags: unit-testing, puppeteer

I have the following CSS code

```
body {
  background: white;    
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 980px) /* Desktop */ {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

How to emulate device size with puppeteer? `page.setVieport()` or `--window-size` don't work because it emulates viewport size (not device).

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a device using the [page.emulate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/7fded54903d25206031631a4d3a78aec61b38db9/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions) function.

Example from the docs:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6'];

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
});
```

If you don't find your device on the devices list you can build your own and passing that to `emulate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`deviceScaleFactor`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions) to scale the device width in relation to the viewport.

Here is an example for the [viewport of the iPhone 4](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/5e21ba3cbbe455317158e6a4fc5af2808abd45df/lib/DeviceDescriptors.js#L235):

```js
{
    'width': 320,
    'height': 480,
    'deviceScaleFactor': 2,
    // ...
}
```

In this example, the `deviceWidth` of the device is emulated as `320` although the true width of the viewport (actual number of pixels of the device) is `640` (`320 * 2`). That means, provide the device width to `page.emulate` and use `deviceScaleFactor` to scale the viewport accordingly.

Alternatively, you can also use one of the many [already existing devices](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/5e21ba3cbbe455317158e6a4fc5af2808abd45df/lib/DeviceDescriptors.js) (via [`puppeteer.devices`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.18.1/docs/api.md#puppeteerdevices)) when calling `page.emulate`.